# Form checkbox using AJAX always showing ON with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a checkbox as such

```
<input name="notify" type="checkbox" id="notify" class="notify" />
```

I am using an ajax call as such

```
$("form#submit").submit(function() {
// we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
var username = $('#username').attr('value');
var email = $('#email').attr('value');
var password = $('#password').attr('value');
var cpassword = $('#cpassword').attr('value');
var notify = $('#notify').attr('value');
var session_user_id = $('#session_user_id').attr('value');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../../includes/editprofile.php?",
data: "username="+ username+
    "&email="+ email+
    "&password="+ password+
    "&cpassword="+ cpassword+
    "&notify="+ notify+
    "&session_user_id="+ session_user_id,
success: function(data){
$('div.success').fadeIn();
$('div.success').html(data);
}
});
return false;
});
```

In my editprofile.php file I am simply echo'n $notify to see what the value is after I submit the form and no matter what its always "on" whether I check the box or not. Any clues?

Comment: have to use post ....like echo $notifi=$_POST['notify'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#notify').attr('checked') ? "True" : "False";
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I will check it as answer as soon as I can

Comment: I dont think there is any need to write `? "True" : "False"`, because it'll definitely return either true or false, isn't it ?

Comment: @Deepanshu- yes off-course, but we can set value for it instead of true/false. I just made single line code that's it.

Answer (score 3):

all 3 should work below

try

```
$('#notify').is(':checked');
```

or

```
$('#notify').attr('checked');
```

or

```
$('#notify').prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
var notify = $('#notify').attr('value');
```

to

```
var notify = $('#notify').attr('checked');
```

Because `checkbox` does not have `value`

Comment: Just did and it always returns "undefined"